# Prevent Image Drag Selection

Tags: javascript, image, select, drag

I have looked all over the internet, but have found nothing that works.

I want my image not to be selected, like a div with a background image (`<div style = "background-image : 'moo.png';"> </div>`)

I can't use a background image, because I need an image map for functionality.

my code looks like this:

css,

```
.filmmakers #map {

-moz-user-select : -moz-none;
-khtml-user-select : none;
-webkit-user-select : none;
-ms-user-select : none;
-o-user-select : none;
user-select : none;

}

.filmmakers #map::selection {

   color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

html,

```
<img id = "map" src = "WorldMap.png" alt = "Map" unselectable = "on" style = "left : 0px; top : 0px;" />
```

javascript,

```
var map = document.getElementById('map');

makeUnselectable(map);

function makeUnselectable(node) {

if (node.nodeType == 1) {

   node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");

}

   var child = node.firstChild;

while (child) {

   makeUnselectable(child);
   child = child.nextSibling;

}

}
```

As you can see, I still get the drag icon and it messes with the functionality of the map:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107533178/CampusRoyal/Filmmakers.html

Please help and thanks for taking the time to read my post, I really appreciate your kind attention.

Cheers!

Mithos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need:

```
window.ondragstart = function() { return false; }
```

If you are using jQuery

```
$("img").mousedown(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: But now the image doesn't drag at all?

Comment: Have you tried this window.ondragstart = function() { return false; }

Comment: I can see an error on this page:  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107533178/CampusRoyal/Filmmakers.html. Fix that error and try JS, it should work

Comment: I misunderstood you! Thank you so much ^^ cheers! and +1 for fast, helpful and simple answers

Answer (score -1):

Answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135622/1722914

User this css :

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```